# show enum in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, enums

i have enum

```
 public enum TypeImage
{
    Img=0,
    Thumb=1
}
```

i want in view show <%= TypeImage.Img %> -it shows "img" but not 0. what the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
<%= Convert.ToInt32(TypeImage.Img) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show 0 you need to cast enum to integer:

```
<%= (int)TypeImage.Img %>
```